# what outbound firewall rules do I need for a KMS Windows activation server?

Tags: windows-activation

I know that inbound the port 1688 is needed..but I'm wondering what port I need to open *outbound*?
...and I'm wondering what IP ranges I need to set

any help gratefully received

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow return traffic to the client calling the KMS server. Nothing else.
The connection will purely be established by the client, which needs to receive the response. There is some back and forth, but everything is initiated as a TCP connection from the client side and the KMS server just responds.
So something along the lines of:
`permit tcp <client range> kms-server eq 1688`
`permit tcp kms-server <client range>`

Comment: Hi thanks for that Tonny, but I was meaning how does the KMS server communicate sort of externally with Microsoft? Do I need a rule saying allow *.microsoft.com on port 1688 or something like that?

Comment: KMS doesn’t talk to Microsoft at all. It is a standalone service that issues licenses from a pool that it internally manages.